# Vector space and span?

Tags: vector-spaces

[image]Good morning

If we have $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_m$ ,$m$ vectors spaces,and each vector $v_j\in Xj$, and the notation $\langle \rangle$ mean span.

Then what mean this notation please :

$$X_k \not\subset \langle \{v_j:j\neq k\}\rangle.$$
Does it mean that vector space $X_k$ not belong to the span generate by each vector $v_j$ such that  $j\neq k$, or not belong to the span generate by all vectors $v_j$.
Examle $m=4$ so $$X_1 \not\subset \langle \{v_2,v_3,v_4\}\rangle \text{ and  } X_2 \not\subset \langle \{v_1,v_3,v_4\}\rangle \text{ and  } X_3 \not\subset \langle \{v_1,v_2,v_4\}\rangle\text{ and  } X_4 \not\subset \langle \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}\rangle.$$
or
$$X_1 \not\subset \langle \{v_2\}\rangle  \text{ and  } X_2 \not\subset \langle \{v_1\}\rangle.$$
and
$$X_1 \not\subset \langle \{v_3\}\rangle.$$
and
 $$X_1 \not\subset \langle \{v_4\}\rangle.$$

Which of them is correct, please.

Comment: How could the span be all vectors, if they gave you the predicate $j \neq k$? Also, your examples (before and after "or") seem to be the same.

Comment: It was a mistake and i have corrected.

Comment: Excuse me now the question is right

Comment: The examples still seem the same to me. $((A \not\subset B)\ \wedge\ (A \not\subset C)) \longrightarrow (A \not\subset (B \cup C))$.

Comment: my question is $X_1$ does not belong to the span generated by  all vectors $v_1$,$v_2$,$v_3$ or the idivudial span

Comment: $X_1$ is not *contained* (the term `belong` is inappropriate here: $X_11$ is not a vector) in the span of $v_2, v_2,v_4$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe if a vector space $X_1$ is not contained within the span of a set of vectors, then $X_1$ is also not contained within the span of each vector element.

Comment: ok you can see the answer of AlgebraicallyClosed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $\{ v_{j} : j \neq k\}$ is the following set $$S=\{v_{1},v_{2},\dots,v_{k-1},v_{k+1},\dots,v_{m-1},v_{m}\}$$

So you have that the vector space $X_{k} \not\subset \langle S \rangle$.

Furthermore, you will have that $$X_{k} \not\subset \langle v_{i} \rangle \ \forall i \neq k,$$
because if it was a subset of these "spans", then it will be contained in the span of S. But see that this is derived from the definition of $S$ and the definition is that $$S=\{v_{1},v_{2},\dots,v_{k-1},v_{k+1},\dots,v_{m-1},v_{m}\}.$$

But you could deduce from $$X_{k} \not\subset \langle v_{i} \rangle \ \forall i \neq k$$
that $X_{k} \not\subset \langle S \rangle$.

I think you are asking about the definiton of the set $S$.

Comment: yes about the definition of the set $\{v_i:i\neq j\}$ mean all vector except $v_j$

Comment: and thank you so much i will add pictur to see from were i have this problem

Comment: @MokhTarBou Yes, it is the first option of that you propose.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your help.